# Event bus message not received when executing blocking code

Tags: vert.x

Here's the thing, let's say there are 2 verticles in a cluster over Hazelcast. Verticle 1 is sending loads of messages via event bus to Verticle 2. V2 consumes these messages, splits their contents into bulks and inserts these bulks into a database. The problem is that while the bulks are being inserted, some messages are not consumed by the verticle 2. Verticle 1 reports that it didn't recieve reply in 30s.

Question is, what is the best way to process the bulks so the messages could be consumed? I've started with vertx.executeBlocking, then I tried to create separate shared worker executor and execute with it. My last try was deploying new verticle that does the processing in "start" method.

What is the recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

Deploying a new verticle is definitely wrong. In Vert.x the idea is that verticles are long living and do the processing. All operations that might take long, if possible should be done async (like using an async DB driver) or if not possible then as sync code in worker verticles.

You can deploy many instances of the (worker) verticles and they can all consume the same topic, this is how work will be done in parallel. By not blocking a normal (=non worker) verticle you let the thread be free and next instance of that same verticle will pick up next event and start processing it (instead of blocking the thread waiting for DB).

Comment: Would it help to deploy number of worker verticles from the one verticle and delegate the bulks to them via event bus? Or would the worker verticles block event loop of the main verticle that deployed them? What I mean that when the Verticle 2 is starting it'd deploy a number of worker verticles that would do the database inserts.

Comment: no, communication over eventbus is NOT blocking and this is the model for scaling in Vert.x. Each Vertx application has a main verticle that deploy other ones. Those (worker or not) will handle events and communicate over event bus without blocking each other.
So you V2 should deploy multiple instances of a worker verticle that listen to eventbus and do the processing

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind [Vertx golden rule](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_dont_block_me) ;  ***don’t block the event loop***,

- perform the blocking operations of V2 in worker threads which will be executed asynchronously.
- Use Async handlers that will be called when the
  future completes and the result is available
- Use result (For example succeeded, or failure) from handlers to continue operation.